# Why is the FileManager.default.enumerator 3x faster with URL than String in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I needed to traverse a large part (500k+ files) of the file tree, and switched from passing the `FileManager.default.enumerator()` a `String` to a `URL`. The traverse becomes 3x faster, and I am looking to understand why.

I'm testing on my Mac with an APFS formatted drive.

This is my test code to measure this in a Swift Playground:

```swift
import Cocoa

var startingTime: Date
var pathCount = 0
var urlCount = 0
    
let path = "/Users/tom/myfolder/"
let pathEnumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(atPath: path)

let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let urlEnumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: url, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)


print("== URL Enumerator ==")
startingTime = Date()
while let _ = urlEnumerator?.nextObject() as? URL {
    urlCount += 1
}
print("\n\(urlCount) files.")
print("\(startingTime.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1) seconds elapsed")

print("\n\n")

print("== Path/String Enumerator ==")
startingTime = Date()
while let _ = pathEnumerator?.nextObject() as? String {
    pathCount += 1
}
print("\n\(pathCount) files.")
print("\(startingTime.timeIntervalSinceNow * -1) seconds elapsed")
```

This is the output I get:

```
== URL Enumerator ==

541879 files.
40.580654978752136 seconds elapsed

== Path/String Enumerator ==

541879 files.
118.60869300365448 seconds elapsed
```

If I change the order (do the `String` version first), it makes no difference, so it doesn't appear to be a caching artefact.

Comment: APIs that use `URL` *are* newer and you are recommended to use them, whereas those that take `String`s are supposed to be soft-deprecated. So a performance difference isn't too surprising.

Comment: @Sweeper - Yeah, `URL` based APIs are newer, but it is still an extreme difference, especially as after you have initialised with the path, the work the function has to do shouldn't be too different.

Comment: Have you tried Instruments' "Time Profiler"?

Comment: You should do performance tests in a compiled project, not in a Playground.

Comment: @MartinR - I just tried that, and it is still >2x faster as a compiled command line tool. They are both a lot faster overall though (11s vs 22s), which was a surprise to me. This was useful as I've been obsessing about optimising, when it maybe isn't needed after all.

Comment: @Willeke - Thanks for the suggestion - I'm new to Swift/Xcode so wasn't aware of this tool. I have just tried that now, and it has shed some light on the situation! I am not sure how to post the results other than as an answer, so I'll do that now.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to the suggestion from @Willeke, I ran this from Xcode's "Time Profiler" tool, and looked at the call stack for each path. It has highlighted a difference in behaviour between the two methods.

The call stack for the `URL` approach:

[image: URL call stack]

The call stack for the `String` approach:

[image: String (path) call stack]

My best interpretation of this is that the older `String` API is a recursive crawl of tree, which comes with lots of performance overheads, whereas the newer `URL` API has 'knows' the file tree and can just traverse it iteratively.

@Martin R suggested I check this in a compiled app (which is where the screenshots are from). The difference there is still 2x, but they were both a lot faster (11s vs 22s) than in the Playground.